# Pip exception while installing matplotlib on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I am working in a opencv project on the raspberry pi, and im using a virtual environment, but i used pip to install numpy, scipy and other libraries, but when trying to install matplotlib on pip by:

> pip install matplotlib

it throws an error:

> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
>       functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
>       more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 491, in _prepare_file
>       session=self.session)
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 825, in unpack_url
>       session,
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
>       from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(link, session, temp_dir)
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 886, in _download_http_url
>       _download_url(resp, link, content_file)
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 621, in _download_url
>       for chunk in progress_indicator(resp_read(4096), 4096):
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 133, in iter
>       for x in it:
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 586, in resp_read
>       decode_content=False):
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 307, in stream
>       data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 243, in read
>       data = self._fp.read(amt)
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
>       self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 224, in cache_response
>       self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 81, in dumps
>       ).encode("utf8"),
>   MemoryError

So for now i cant install matplotlib. 
How can i avoid the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I researched a little more an I solved it by using

> pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Like @jacob suggested `pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib` helped to avoid the out of memory error.

However, matplotlib did not build because 'libpng' is not available on the raspberry and cannot be fetched by pip. In this case `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` worked just fine.

Comment: I would also like to add that using apt-get worked better for me. I installed matplotlib using pip `sudo pip install matplotlib` and I was getting some Gdk errors so I unistalled with pip `sudo pip uninstall matplotlib`, then reinstalled with apt-get `sudo apt-get install matplotlib` and it worked just fine.